# UPDATE a Column with a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `FactSales` with the following columns:

```
Revenue, Quantity, UnitCost
```

This is how the table looks like:

```
UnitCost   | Revenue | Quantity
-----------+---------+----------
NULL       | 50.0    | 5
NULL       | 70.0    | 3
```

Now I want to update the data in `UnitCost` to be equal to `Revenue / Quantity`, how ever when using the following query

```
UPDATE FactSales 
SET UnitCost = (SELECT Revenue / Quantity
                FROM FactSales);
```

I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How should the update statement be written as to successfully update the values?

Comment: You should never have a table column that can be derived from other columns! What is this for? You could either use a view, or just get the UnitCost in whatever application is using this table

Comment: I agree that this is bad practice, but I personally didn't decide on this specification sadly.

Comment: Can you try: UPDATE FactSales 
SET UnitCost = (
FactSales.Revenue / FactSales.Quantity
);

Comment: Stop - just stop and think. It is obvious that you have multiple rows in FactSales.  So is your intent to update EVERY SINGLE ROW? If so, what values from which row(s) do you want to use in your calculation for each row? Presumably you want to use the values from each row to update the column in that same row. If so, stickybit provides the solution. If not, then you need to provide more information. Do this by providing a small sample of rows. In addition, it is difficult to believe that you have a fact table with just those three columns. Oversimplified?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use a subquery, just an expression is enough.

```
UPDATE FactSales 
       SET UnitCost = Revenue / Quantity;
```

Your subquery retrieves more than one row, if the table has more than one row. But in the given context only subqueries returning not more that one row are allowed. But in your query a subquery isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

your query analysis

```
UPDATE FactSales 
SET UnitCost = (
SELECT Revenue / Quantity
FROM FactSales
);
```

here in this subquery returns multiple values, SQL is complaining because it can't assign multiple values to `UnitCost`

```
(
    SELECT Revenue / Quantity
    FROM FactSales
    );


    output 
 Revenue / Quantity
    10 --1st row
    23.333333333333332 --2nd row
```

as a result it throws that error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression

So void using sub-query just do it in single query like below

```
UPDATE FactSales 
       SET UnitCost = Revenue / Quantity; --here for each row single value will return
```

Note:This is not permitted when the

> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= means for this type of operators not allowed multiple values in sql engine .